# FireDAC query returns empty blob

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, firedac

I'm using Delphi XE7 and FireDA* to write a console app to compare two Firebird (2.5) databases, and generate an SQL patch with the differences. I'm almost finished, however the views are giving me trouble. I'm trying to read the view source (SQL) from table `rdb$relations`, field `rdb$view_source` (a text blob) with the following query:

```sql
SELECT RDB$VIEW_SOURCE as VIEW_SRC
FROM RDB$RELATIONS
WHERE RDB$VIEW_SOURCE IS NOT NULL
      AND RDB$RELATION_NAME = UPPER(:rel_name)
```

However, upon execution it returns an empty column, and I can't figure why; and yes, said column has a value, I can see it in IBExpert. Same query works in IBExpert, and also works if I use IBObjects, but not in FireDAC. If I remove the parameter it returns five records (database has five views), but all have the field VIEW_SRC empty.

I'm just using FDConnection and FDQuery components, nothing else; also, all components are using default property values.

Things I've already tried:

- Increasing InlineDataSize from 1000 to MAXINT;
- Made a separate Windows app with FireDAC and a grid to show results, didn't work.
- Made a separate Windows app with IBObjects and a grid to show results, worked ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the query produces results in IBExpert, then the problem is with your Delphi code. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's just components placed on the form - there isn't any code involved, apart from that SQL query, that is...just dropped components, set query, and when executed FireDAC produces a result, but the column is blank...switching components to IBObjects returns the correct result in the column. I can't figure out why this is happening, except that maybe I missed something has to be configured in FireDAC either at FDConnection or FDQuery...or it has a bug in that version.

Comment: How do you check that "the column is blank"?

Comment: @user13964273 reading its value with a simple FieldByName('column_name').AsString returns a empty string, or dropping a grid (one that has proper controls to show blob fields), that's to name two, any proper Delphi method for checking the value of something will return a empty string. Maybe it's semantics, I should have used "empty" and not "blank".